# How to keep track of dynamically added nodes using MutationObserver?

Tags: javascript, dom, google-chrome-extension, mutation-observers

**Context:**
The code is from the "content-script" of a chrome extension.

Given a target node, i would like to get every childNode(a div) and add a button on it.

I tried the simplest solution:

```
const target = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
const childNodes = target.childNodes;
childNodes.forEach(node => { //some function that add a button on this node});
```

Obviously, it works untill i scroll down the page, when new nodes are added on the DOM, and I can't keep track of them anymore.

Thus i decided to try with MutationObserver:

```
const target = document.querySelector(targetSelector);
const config = { childList: true, subtree: true };

const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
  for (const mutation of mutationList) {
      console.log(mutation); //it doesn't return the node, but some kind of mutation object, so i can't get the refernce and work whit it.    
  } 
};

const observer = new MutationObserver(callback);

observer.observe(target,config);
```

There's a solution? Can i finally keep track of new added nodes and work with them?

**EDIT:** As @Jridyard suggested, i tried both "target" property and "mutation.addedNodes" property.
This partially fixed the problem, in the sense that I finally got the references to the nodes initially, but not the dynamically loaded ones in the DOM, getting this error when I try to access the innerText property.

```
index2.js:52 Uncaught TypeError: Cannot read properties of undefined (reading 'innerText')
    at MutationObserver.callback
```

Example:

```
const callback = (mutationList, observer) => {
        for(const mutation of mutationList) {
            //works with the initially loaded nodes,not tracking the others dinamically loaded after page scroll.
            /*if(mutation.target.classList[0] === "Comment") {
                console.log(mutation.target.innerText);
            } */ 
  
            //works with the initially loaded nodes, the gives me the above error with the others nodes dinamically loaded after page scroll.
            if(mutation.addedNodes[0] !== null) {
                console.log(mutation.addedNodes[0].innerText);
            }     
        }
    };
```

Comment: Why can't you keep track of the existing nodes after you scroll? That doesn't make sense by itself - if the elements still exist, you should be able to keep referencing them. Can you include a MCVE in your question?

Comment: Just use `target.childNodes` whenever you need the list, don't use the variable `childNodes`. It will always have the dynamic list.

Comment: @CertainPerformance taking as an example a discussion on Reddit, after a certain number of comments, they are loaded into the dom dynamically, as the page is scrolled. so i can't keep track of them without a mutationObserver, but with a mutationObserver i acrually can't get the reference to the comment node.

Comment: @Edoardo Why can't you get it with the mutation object? the mutation object has a "target" property and in the case that nodes are added you can view the added nodes in the "mutation.addedNodes" property. Have you tried that?

Comment: You can add an inner loop over `mutation.addedNodes` as shown in every(?) example for MutationObserver or you can use document.querySelectorAll to find the nodes that weren't yet processed assuming you added a class to them when you process them.

Comment: @Jridyard I tried your suggestions, see the edit, but not working as expected.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I finally found a solution (not written by me, courtesy of a reddit user) and figured out that the initial problem stemmed from Reddit.
Because I tried to do the same on youtube and it worked fine.
In practice Reddit updates parts of a comment at different times, so simply monitoring the added nodes(as I did above) was not enough, but the comments had to be parsed after each mutation in the DOM.
Probably computationally very inefficient, but currently working.

The code below shows the solution tailored for reddit:

```
function processComment(comment)
{
    const avatar_link = comment.querySelector("[data-testid=comment_author_icon]");
    const user_link = avatar_link?.getAttribute("href");
    const user_picture_link = avatar_link?.querySelector("img")?.getAttribute("src");
    
    const user_name = comment.querySelector("[data-testid=comment_author_link]")?.textContent;
    const body = comment.querySelector("[data-testid=comment]")?.textContent;
    
    return {
        user_link,
        user_picture_link,
        user_name,
        body,
        div: comment,
    };
    
}
 
function getComments(parent)
{
    return [...(parent ?? document).querySelectorAll(".Comment")].map(processComment);
}
 
function observeComments(callback, parent)
{
    parent ??= document;
    
    const mo = new MutationObserver(() => getComments(parent).map(callback));
    
    mo.observe(parent, {attributes: true, childList: true, subtree: true});
    
    return mo;
}
 
observeComments((m)=>console.log(m.body));
```